# How can I run jsx in Blazor?

Tags: c#, jsx, blazor

I can call a JS method directly from razor pages via the `IJSRuntime` interface.
But I can't run a method written in JSX syntax.
If I try, it throws an obvious error.

So, is there any way to use JSX syntax in Blazor?

Here is a code example -

```
window.RenderReact = () => {
    const Message = () => React.createElement(
        Fabric.MessageBar,
        {
            label: "React Message",
            ariaLabel: count,
            truncated: true
        },
        React.createElement("h1", null,"Hello")
    );
    ReactDOM.render(Message(), document.getElementById('reactContent'));
}
```

This block of code should run if I write like this -

```
window.RenderReact = () => {
    const hello = <h1>Hello</h1>
    const Message = () => React.createElement(
        Fabric.MessageBar,
        {
            label: "React Message",
            truncated: true
        },
        hello
    );
    ReactDOM.render(Message(), document.getElementById('reactContent'));
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you don't mix both technologies in the same page. Both are shadow Dom and it wouldn't surprise me at all if conflicts arise. That said, if you do mix them, treat them as completely separate and let the react app build and run on its own. If you need to connect the apps, it is through js interoo

Comment: I'm just exploring the possibilities. I know I can transpile JSX inside Blazor. But don't know how, so I need an answer to fill my curious mind. :D